# iPhone4 Compatibility Issues

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, xib

I just developed new iOS App (for iPhone 5 only, its working as expected) but need to make it compatible for iPhone 4.

I already embedded

```
- (void) loadView
{
    [super loadView];
    self.view.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
}
```

And set Size of nib equals to **None** in **Attribute Inspector**.

Well yes I don't want to make two **XIBs** and can't remove auto sizing masks restrictions. Finding some other good solutions. Now what to do with those 88 pixels short in **iPhone4**?

Again pardon me for asking such a common question but need to know how to make app compatible from **iPhone5 4 inch retina display** to **iPhone4 3.5 inch retina display**

Many Thanks.

Comment: Wow it looks from your images that you dont have any way of shortening your screen 88px less :( you will have to design it for iPhone4 and then decide what to do. I know you are asking a technical question but I think you need your designer to think first where to put the things in a smaller screen

Comment: You can give up the Ad on the bottom for iPhone 3.5 inch no?

Answer (score 0):

other than u can do it make lot of complex and it's not good way to implementing. try autosizing via programmatically if you not use xib/storyboard

only xib

[image]

Comment: I implemented one single XIB. Exactly dont want to make things complicated